# About the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty xe^{-nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

I was looking up how to prove the integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-1} dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$

and came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685686/how-to-solve-int-x-ex-1-dx). In the accepted answer, it is apparent that there is the following step:
$$
\int_0^\infty \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty xe^{-nx}\right) dx = 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty xe^{-nx}dx
$$

Of course, the above interchange is only possible provided the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty xe^{-nx}$ converges uniformly. However, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2916774/does-sum-infty-n-1xe-nx-converge-uniformly-on-0-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694293/is-series-sum-n-1-infty-xe-nx-uniformly-convergent) seems to say that the series does **not** converge uniformly.

So is the proof in the first post still valid? Thanks!

Comment: Sum up to $N$ only, take $N\to +\infty$ and use the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Gary So the series is uniformly convergent? Because the other posts seems to suggest it is not, unless I am reading it wrongly...

Comment: Uniform convergence is sufficient but not necessary.

Comment: @Gary I do not understand. Sorry, English is not my first language.

Comment: You do not need uniform convergence to prove the statement, a weaker assumption is enough. Look up the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Gary you mean the swapping of the integral and summation is justified solely from monotone convergence theorem? Without the need of uniform convergence?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Use the theorem with $$
f_n (x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {xe^{ - kx} } .
$$

Comment: @Gary Thank you! Let me read it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you restrict yourself into the frame of Riemannian integrals, you might notice that $\sum_1^\infty x \mathrm e^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on every $[c, +\infty) \subset (0, + \infty)$, so you argue as follows
\begin{align*}
\mathrm {LHS} &= \lim_{ {c \to 0^+}} \lim_{A \to +\infty} \int_c^{A} \sum_1^\infty x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x \notag \\
&= \lim_{ {c \to 0^+}} \lim_{A \to +\infty} \sum_1^\infty \int_c^{A}  x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x \tag {1}\label{first_uni}\\
&= \lim_{ {c \to 0^+}} \sum_1^\infty \lim_{A \to +\infty}  \int_c^{A}  x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x \tag {2}\label{2nd_uni}\\
&= \lim_{ {c \to 0^+}} \sum_1^\infty   \int_c^{+\infty}  x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x \\
&=  \sum_1^\infty \lim_{ {c \to 0^+}} \int_c^{+\infty}    x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x \tag {3}\label{3rd_uni}\\
&= \sum_1^\infty  \int_0^{+\infty}    x\mathrm e^{-nx} \operatorname d\!x,
\end{align*}

where $\eqref{first_uni}$ holds because of the uniform convergence of $\sum_1^\infty x \mathrm e^{-nx}$ on $[c,A]$, $\eqref{2nd_uni}$ follows from the uniform convergence of $\sum_1^\infty \int_c^A x \mathrm  e^{-nx}\ \mathrm dx$ w.r.t. $A\in [1, +\infty)$ [as a series of functions of $A$], and $\eqref{3rd_uni}$ is true since $\sum_1^\infty \int_c^{+\infty} x \mathrm e^{-nx } \ \mathrm dx$ converges uniformly on $c \in [0,1/4]$.

Of course, these could be significantly simplified if you are allowed to use the MCT[monotone convergence theory] from Lebesgue integration theory.

**UPDATE**

The uniform convergence **of course would vary w.r.t. to the interval you are looking at**. In this question, the convergence is uniform on any $[c, +\infty) \subset (0,+\infty)$, NOT on $(0, +\infty)$. Note that every $f_n (x) = x \mathrm e^{-nx}$ reach its maximum at $x = 1/n$ on $(0, +\infty)$, so for some $1/N < c$, $f_n (x) <= f_n(c) =c\mathrm e^{-nc}$ for any $n \geqslant N$, and $\sum_N^\infty f_n(c)$ converges **as a normal numerical series**, so by the Weierstraß $M$-test, $\sum_N^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[c, +\infty)$ hence also on $[c,A]$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have a small issue with (1), the other 2 posts that i have put in the answer above seems to suggest that the series $\sum_1^\infty xe^{-nx}$ does NOT converge uniformly, do you have any comments about that?

Comment: @D.Soul When talking about uniform convergence, one always needs to indicate the interval.

Comment: Thank you! You have been very patient! Will accept the answer in a bit.

Comment: Sorry, if I may, could I ask if you have an intuitive explanation (sort of a picture, rather than mathematical) as to why the addition of a single point $x=0$ destroys the uniform convergence?